# Read Only column - After initial edit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to make a Digital Signature column in a list read only after initial signing. Can someone assist me in how to do this?  Similar to how you would write an update trigger in a database I'm assuming but don't know how to do this with SharePoint lists...

Comment: nice question. Sadly, as now the only solution that comes in mind is to have the field read-only and use some custom edit / new forms to manage the special rule. I will check if I can think of anything better.

Comment: A workflow can do elevated permissions and write/update an item to a(nother) List the user does not have access to

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention database triggers, I must say you can write similar functionality on SharePoint using event receivers.

They are a bit tricky the first time you are doing, but they will certainly help you get what you need.

At the most basic level, try to override item updating method in your event receiver. This will get triggered as soon as the user clicks "save" button, and before the changes are written to the DB. 
Now you can access the item's properties before and after the user made the change, and as per your Validation logic, if a particular field was supposed to be read-only and if it is changing, you can return an error with appropriate message.

To improve above that you should look to create a custom edit item form in SP designer, where user doesn't get access to the read-only field at all.